# Can you protect People with the Death Note by writing their name in it?

Tags: death-note

A person whose name is written in a death note is immune to all other death notes. Are they immune to a bullet to the head or eating an arsenic cream pie, too? If so, would they have a sort of "luck shield" that stops any potential causes of death from making it impossible to fulfill the death note entry, or would they just survive it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The death note cannot lengthen a person's life span by setting a date of death for that person after their current date of death.  In this case the person would just die as they would if their name was not written.  This is from "How to Use LVII".

I was wrong on one account originially.  If you write a person's name in the death note and do not edit it for 6 minutes and 40 seconds (400 seconds as that is how long you can edit it), then he is immune from other death notes.  This is due to "How to Use XV" which states that if the same name is in two death notes, the first filled in will take effect.  This can only protect for 23 days as the person will die by then anyways.  It appears that this can be circumvented by editing it every 6 minutes and 40 seconds.

You can, however, do the following.  If you know Dusk is trying to kill Dawn, you can write Dusk will "be killed by Dawn after failing to even scratch her with his attacks". This means he must die of either a heart attack because the cause of death could not happen (could not reasonably get to Dawn or Dawn killing Dusk is impossible) or will be killed by Dawn with hurting her.  In any case you need Dusk's name and you are extending Dawn's life by killing Dusk with the death note which humans (not Shinigami) can intentionally do.

Comment: So if i would write: John Zeürtö Heart Attack in 23 Days. And someone would try to shoot him, would he have some sort of a luck shield or would the other person successfully kill him?

Comment: The other would kill him (assuming he isnt just a reallly terrible shot regardless of the death note)

Comment: Ah but if i would write: John Zeürtö Heart Attack in 23 Days. However everybody who attempts to kill him, won't be able to do so. Would that work?

Comment: He already had a lifespan above is head the shinigami can read. That correlates with the gunshot.  If the date of death is beyond that natural lifespan it does not take effect.

Comment: but if it's within his lifespan he wouldn't die right?

Comment: his lifespan is decided by when someone would come to shoot him without influence of the death note.  Ergo, if it is within his lifespan it would be a non-fatal shooting anyways.

Comment: So that means someone if someone is fated to kill you, will you get trouble with that person. Anyway if this is true, that means that people who get killed by a serial killer are already destined to get murdered by that serial killer? But let's say the FBI catches him and he get's executed. That means, that this would extend the lifespan of many people since the person who kill won't be able to do so.

Comment: Yes. But also he was fated to be caught unless a death note entry somehow got him caught

Comment: But if i would out of stupidity order some thug to kill me with a gun, and i would kill him then with my death note when he's about to kill me. Would i then extend my lifespan?

Comment: You can extend your lifespan by killing someone else.  what I don't know is what would happen if a death note death prevents a death that was written prior.

Comment: @kaine I would expect any deaths that become impossible due to earlier deaths (i.e. the planned killer being killed) to be replaced with heart attacks.

Comment: @Brilliand maybe but i think it might be undefined behavior. I dont nnow what would happen. If you get a copy i guess u could try it out to satify curiousity